Converging a Quantum Espresso PW geometry relaxation for a perovskite structure
I have been trying to perform a geometry relaxation of a CsPbI3 perovskite for several weeks now. I know that this structure converges with the same thresholds in CASTEP. I am using the PAW pseudos from PSLibrary. I have tried to modify almost all parameters: changing the thresholds, ecutrho, specifying the ibrav number, changing the mixing beta to lower numbers... everything, and yet nothing. After more than 40 tests, it never converged. It never performed more than 70 cycles. This can not be that hard, I am sure it has to be a stupid mistake so obvious that neither me or my colleagues are able to spot. I would kindly appreciate any help.
This is the input in question:
! CsPbI3 relaxation test - Pablo Gila-Herranz 
! Structure from CsPbI3-pnma.cif with cif2cell

&CONTROL
  calculation = 'vc-relax'
  prefix = 'CsPbI3'
  outdir = './tmp/'
  pseudo_dir = './pseudos/'
  restart_mode = 'from_scratch'
  max_seconds = 21000
  etot_conv_thr = 1.4699728870266317d-12
  forc_conv_thr = 3.889380759660317e-07
  tprnfor = .true.
  tstress = .true.
  nstep = 999
/

&SYSTEM
  ecutwfc = 44.099186610798945
!  ecutrho = 352.79349288639156
  ibrav = 0
  A =    8.86370
  nat = 20
  ntyp = 3
  input_dft = 'PBEsol'
!  vdw_corr = 'DFT-D3'
!  dftd3_version = 4
!  dftd3_threebody = .true.
  occupations = 'fixed'
/

&ELECTRONS
  adaptive_thr = .true.
  conv_thr = 1.4699728870266317d-12
  mixing_beta = 0.7d0
  electron_maxstep = 999
/

&IONS
  ion_dynamics = 'bfgs'
  trust_radius_max = 1.8897261259077822d-06
/

&CELL
  cell_dynamics = 'bfgs'
!  press = 0.0001
!  press_conv_thr = 0.0001
/

K_POINTS (automatic)
  2 2 2 1 1 1

CELL_PARAMETERS {alat}
  1.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000 
  0.000000000000000   1.408418606225391   0.000000000000000 
  0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.967801256811490 
ATOMIC_SPECIES
  Cs  132.90500  Cs.pbesol-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
  Pb  207.20000  Pb.pbesol-dn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
   I  126.90400  I.pbesol-dn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS {crystal}
Pb   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000 
Pb   0.500000000000000   0.500000000000000   0.500000000000000 
Pb   0.500000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.500000000000000 
Pb   0.000000000000000   0.500000000000000   0.000000000000000 
Cs   0.438390000000000   0.250000000000000   0.020060000000000 
Cs   0.061610000000000   0.750000000000000   0.520060000000000 
Cs   0.561610000000000   0.750000000000000   0.979940000000000 
Cs   0.938390000000000   0.250000000000000   0.479940000000000 
 I   0.503030000000000   0.250000000000000   0.564580000000000 
 I   0.996970000000000   0.750000000000000   0.064580000000000 
 I   0.496970000000000   0.750000000000000   0.435420000000000 
 I   0.003030000000000   0.250000000000000   0.935420000000000 
 I   0.198710000000000   0.032720000000000   0.304450000000000 
 I   0.301290000000000   0.532720000000000   0.804450000000000 
 I   0.301290000000000   0.967280000000000   0.804450000000000 
 I   0.801290000000000   0.532720000000000   0.695550000000000 
 I   0.801290000000000   0.967280000000000   0.695550000000000 
 I   0.698710000000000   0.467280000000000   0.195550000000000 
 I   0.698710000000000   0.032720000000000   0.195550000000000 
 I   0.198710000000000   0.467280000000000   0.304450000000000 


Didn't you just ask this question earlier? Oh, I saw it in P.SE. If you have this converged in CASTEP, have you inserted the exact relaxed positions and lattice parameters from CASTEP into this? Try to not change anything, be as equivalent as possible. I still think your thresholds are too tight to converge; you probably should start from bigger thresholds, and let the system reduce the thresholds itself as it converges towards the fixed point.

Thanks @naturallyInconsistent. We are trying to reproduce the CASTEP results in QE, with the same parameters. If I am not mistaken, letting the system reduce the thresholds means having adaptive_thr = .true., right? Unfortunately it does not work.

It is not just with it set to true. You should pick wider thresholds and/or defaults and just give the system some chance to do things on its own, and then re-run at tighter thresholds later. Especially if you can start the tighter thresholds from the wavefunctions that satisfied the looser thresholds, rather than from scratch. Don't make the computer do difficult tasks for no good reason.

Thanks for the feedback. I will try to go with the default thresholds and see how it performs then.
